# Why does adding this function to a web page prevents all other functions/events from occuring?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am tryring to create a form which takes user input and validates it. Currently I am working on client-side validation. Every function was working fine, but as soon as I add a function to occur when the submit button is clicked, all other function stop.

```
function validateForm()
{
    var firstName=document.forms["myForm"]["reg_fname"].value;
    var lastName=document.forms["myForm"]["reg_lname"].value;
    var u=document.forms["myForm"]["reg_username"].value;
    var e1=document.forms["myForm"]["reg_email"].value;
    var e2=document.forms["myForm"]["reg_email2"].value;
    var p1=document.forms["myForm"]["reg_password"].value;
    var p2=document.forms["myForm"]["reg_password2"].value;
    var birthdate=document.forms["myForm"]["reg_birthdate"].value;
    var c=document.forms["myForm"]["country"].value;
    var g=document.forms["myForm"]["gender"].value;
    if (firstName==null || firstName=="",lastName==null || lastName=="",u==null || u=="",e1==null || e1=="",,e2==null || e2=="",,p1==null || p1=="",p2==null || p2=="",birthdate==null || birthdate=="",c==null || c=="",g==null || g=="")
    {
        alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the function. And this is the submit button:-

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="register" onclick="validateForm()" name="register_button" id="register_button">Login</button>
```

Now all other events on other fileds like onkeyup(), onblur() etc. have stopped functioning. Why is this happening and what should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use comma but if you do only last part will be evaluated, rest of the part will be ignored

Comment: @brk It would be valid syntax - but not `,,` like in this case (e.g. `e1=="",,e2==null`).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think that the problem is with `,`. If you want two values in javascript, use `&&` instead of `,`.